# CORS On Google Cloud Storage is broken

Tags: cors, google-cloud-storage

This curl request is for CORS:

```
> curl -H "Origin: http://DOMAIN-WE-REQUEST-FROM" https://api.github.com -s -D - -o /dev/null
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Server: GitHub.com
Date: Thu, 11 Apr 2013 17:26:32 GMT
Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
Connection: keep-alive
Status: 200 OK
X-RateLimit-Limit: 60
X-RateLimit-Remaining: 58
X-GitHub-Media-Type: github.beta
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
Content-Length: 1729
Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true
Access-Control-Expose-Headers: Link, X-RateLimit-Limit, X-RateLimit-Remaining, X-OAuth-Scopes, X-Accepted-OAuth-Scopes
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
ETag: "b883d9a4fa4fe813d8daafea01b9276b"
Cache-Control: max-age=0, private, must-revalidate
```

The same request to a CORS-enabled domain for Google does not send back the correct headers:

```
> curl -H "Origin: http://DOMAIN-WE-REQUEST-FROM" http://EXAMPLE.storage.googleapis.com/FILE-THAT-WAS-RETURNING-CORS-THIS-MORNING.gif -s -D - -o /dev/null
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Server: HTTP Upload Server Built on Apr 8 2013 13:06:58 (1365451618)
Date: Thu, 11 Apr 2013 17:25:50 GMT
Cache-Control: no-cache, no-transform
Expires: Fri, 11 Apr 2014 17:25:50 GMT
Last-Modified: Thu, 24 Jan 2013 20:58:29 GMT
ETag: "7c21bc009de625eda70e50c9fea4665a"
x-goog-generation: 1359061109538000
x-goog-metageneration: 1
Content-Type: image/gif
x-goog-hash: md5=fCG8AJ3mJe2nDlDJ/qRmWg==
Accept-Ranges: bytes
Content-Length: 111711
```

Our CORS config is correct:

```
> gsutil getcors gs://EXAMPLE
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<CorsConfig>
    <Cors>
        <Origins>
            <Origin>
                http://OTHER-DOMAIN
            </Origin>
            <Origin>
                http://DOMAIN-WE-REQUEST-FROM
            </Origin>
        </Origins>
        <Methods>
            <Method>
                GET
            </Method>
            <Method>
                HEAD
            </Method>
            <Method>
                OPTIONS
            </Method>
            <Method>
                PUT
            </Method>
        </Methods>
        <ResponseHeaders>
            <ResponseHeader>
                accept-encoding
            </ResponseHeader>
            <ResponseHeader>
                cache-control
            </ResponseHeader>
            <ResponseHeader>
                content-length
            </ResponseHeader>
            <ResponseHeader>
                content-type
            </ResponseHeader>
            <ResponseHeader>
                expect
            </ResponseHeader>
            <ResponseHeader>
                if-modified-since
            </ResponseHeader>
            <ResponseHeader>
                origin
            </ResponseHeader>
            <ResponseHeader>
                range
            </ResponseHeader>
            <ResponseHeader>
                referer
            </ResponseHeader>
            <ResponseHeader>
                x-goog-acl
            </ResponseHeader>
            <ResponseHeader>
                x-goog-api-version
            </ResponseHeader>
        </ResponseHeaders>
        <MaxAgeSec>
            300
        </MaxAgeSec>
    </Cors>
</CorsConfig>
```

No CORS. This is breaking our app in production, please respond Google cloud team.

(Google has stated that support will occur here on SO: https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/gs-discussion/wu7vnC-TpT4)

Comment: Why would you assume you would find a Google Cloud Team member waiting to answer support requests here?

Comment: Because they killed the discussion group: https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!forum/gs-discussion leaving me no other option. Unless you have a better idea.

Comment: Specifically: https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/gs-discussion/wu7vnC-TpT4 That is their announcement that support will occur here.

Comment: Google Cloud team member here - this is not the correct place for asking about service outages. Please send these types of questions regarding service to gs-team@google.com

Comment: Hey, @JonathanSimon - would it be possible for you to add something to that effect to your [announcement here](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/gs-discussion/wu7vnC-TpT4)?